# MariaDB: syntax error in Referencing old row

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I'm trying to execute a very basic trigger I've found in [MariaDB's Trigger examples](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/trigger-examples/):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Books_Delete
AFTER DELETE ON Books                 /* See note (a) */
  REFERENCING OLD ROW AS Old         /* See note (b) */
FOR EACH ROW                          /* See note (c) */
  INSERT INTO Books_Deleted_Log
      VALUES (Old.title);             /* See note (d) */
```

This doesn't work because I've a syntax error in my query on line 3: `REFERENCING OLD ROW ...`. In general I'm not able to run any example I find for MariaDB or MySQL. So what is wrong here? I read that the `REFERENCING`-part is not necessary but it won't work without it too. Any trigger query I do is a SQL syntax error. Could this be related to using DBeaver as SQL-Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the trigger to look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Books_Delete
AFTER DELETE ON Books
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN                         /* See note (c) */
    INSERT INTO Books_Deleted_Log(title)
        VALUES (Old.title); 
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

`REFERENCING` is not part of MySQL syntax but is part of MariaDB syntax.

Comment: According to MariaDB's official wiki they use `REFERENCING` syntax. Is there some clean way of avoiding the `DELIMITER` syntax? To me this feels strange to have to change the delimiter all time I want to run a trigger. Tho this looks to be the part I've missing and so my queries failed altogether.

Comment: @CodeShark . . . You need to use `DELIMITER` whenever you have "bodies" of code.  This is an issue because of how SQL defines the semi-colon.  A semicolon ends a statement (by default), but a trigger, stored procedure, or function have multiple statements.

Comment: Note the trigger will fail if the tables and columns do not exist.

Comment: Okay good to know that there is no validation for table names or columns. Thanks Gordon Linoff for your fast support!